# How does CC work on Goblins?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What crowd control effects work on treasure demons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68805/what-crowd-control-effects-work-on-treasure-demons)

As of patch 1.0.5, do goblins use the same mechanics that Elites and Champions use? Are they immune to certain CC effects?

Also, is it possible to stun a goblin when he is opening his portal to reset his cast?

Comment: I think this should be re-opened. The question linked gives conflicting info and no mention of patch 1.0.5.  The answer voted correct contradicts the answer with the most upvotes.

Comment: @Mike The accepted answer isn't supposed to mean it's correct; it's supposed to mean that that answer helped the asker the best.  That said, if it's incorrect, it will get downvoted.  You have enough rep to do so!  Also, duplicate questions happen all the time; the point of Arqade is to have a single, definitive question.  Just because an answer is wrong (and I'm not saying it is), doesn't mean we ask the question again; we answer the question!